# Scala How to use extends with an anonymous class

Tags: scala

Is there a way to extends another class from an Anonymous class in Scala? I means something like

```
abstract class Salutation {
  def saybye(): String = "Bye"
}

class anotherClass() {
  def dummyFunction() = {

    val hello = new {
      def sayhello(): String = "hello" 
    } extends Salutation

    val hi  = hello.sayhello //hi value is "Hello"
    val bye = hello.saybye   //bye value is "bye"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yep, and it looks pretty much the same as it does in Java:

```
abstract class Salutation {
  def saybye: String = "Bye"
}

val hello = new Salutation {
  def sayhello: String = "hello" 
}

val hi = hello.sayhello
val bye = hello.saybye
```

If `Salutation` is an abstract class or trait with a `sayhello` method with the same signature, you'll have provided an implementation; otherwise you'll have created an instance of an anonymous structural type:

```
hello: Salutation{def sayhello: String}
```

Note that calls to the `sayhello` method involve reflection (because of the way structural types are implemented in Scala), so if you're using this method heavily you should probably define a new trait or class.

Comment: I didn't specified it at first, but yes Salutation is abstract... Salutation don't have sayHello, but it have some other function that I need and want to use. Is there another way without creating a "real" class?

Comment: Yes, the code I give above will work, and you'll get an instance of `Salutation{def sayhello: String}` that you can call both methods on.

Comment: Hmmm I am supposed to use it like this : " val hello: Salutation{def sayhello: String} " If so,  how I define what sayhello does and how I instantiate it?

Comment: The type of `hello` (including the `sayhello` method signature) will be inferred—you don't need to write it. The code above is all you need to instantiate the class.

Comment: So I should have something like : " val hello : Salutation{def sayhello: String} = new Salutation {
        def sayhello: String = "hello" 
      } "  If not, I don't understand what I need to write. If so, I get this error : "Cannot resolve constructor"

Answer (score 2):

You need to do:

```
val hello = new Salutation {
    def sayhello(): String = "hello" 
}
```

Comment: You beat me by a minute, but I don't think this kind of context-less, code-only answer is generally a good thing on Stack Overflow—especially in a case like this where there's a lot of potentially confusing nuance.

Comment: I'm sorry, my question wasn't complete... I changed it, should be clearer now :)