# What is structure match in scala

Tags: scala, structural-typing

Few questions regarding structure matching in scala

Question 1) In the following piece of code, am I am able to pass `Bird` and `Plane` to `takeOff` because `Bird` and `Plane` structurally match the object `r` required by take off?

```
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls 

case class Bird (val name: String) extends Object {
        def fly(height: Int):Unit = {println("bird fly")}
}

case class Plane (val callsign: String) extends Object {
        def fly(height: Int):Unit = {println("plane fly")}
}

def takeoff(
            runway: Int,
      r: { val callsign: String; def fly(height: Int):Unit }) = {
  println(r.callsign + " requests take-off on runway " + runway)
  println(r.callsign + " is clear for take-off")
  r.fly(1000)
}
val bird = new Bird("Polly the parrot"){ val callsign = name }
val a380 = new Plane("TZ-987")
takeoff(42, bird)
takeoff(89, a380)
```

Question 2) What is reflectiveCalls? I had to import `scala.language.reflectiveCalls` otherwise I get the warning `reflective access of structural type member value callsign should be enabled by making the implicit value scala.language.reflectiveCalls visible.`

Question 3) How can I create `Bird` as follows: val bird = `new Bird("Polly the parrot"){ val callsign = name }`. Shouldn't it only be `val bird = new Bird("Polly the parrot")`. How come this compiles.

Question 3.1). Is `bird` still of type `Bird` or is it some other type now because I have passed additional `{...}`

4) What is the type of `r` in `takeOff`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes (see #4)
2. Structural typing use reflection in background, so it's slow. `reflectiveCalls` import is used to warn user about this problem.
3. When you add refinement `{ val callsign = name }` you extend you type `Bird` with extra field `callsign`, so now its type matches `r` as it has both `callsign` and `fly`

   3.1 The type of `bird` is both `Bird` and structural

   ```
   val bird: Bird = new Bird("Polly the parrot"){ val callsign = name }
   val birdRefined: Bird{ val callsign:String } = new Bird("Polly the parrot"){ val callsign = name }
   val structuralBird: { val callsign: String; def fly(height: Int): Unit } = birdRefined
   ```
4. Its called [`Duck typing`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) or [structural type](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#structural-types) in scala.

You may also be interested in this subtyping relations

```
implicitly[Bird <:< { def fly(height: Int):Unit }]
//implicitly[Bird <:< { val callsign: String; def fly(height: Int):Unit }] -- fails. Not sybtype. 
implicitly[Plane <:< { val callsign: String; def fly(height: Int):Unit }]
implicitly[Bird {val callsign:String} <:< { val callsign: String; def fly(height: Int):Unit }]
```

Comment: 3.1 isn't really a good demonstration, because this would apply to `val bird2 = new Bird("")` as well.

Answer (score 2):

- Regarding Q1: Yes they structurally match type of `r`
- Regarding Q2 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26788585/5205022
- Regarding Q3 and 3.1 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24657641/5205022
- Regarding Q4 the type of `r` is

```
r: AnyRef{val callsign: String; def fly(height: Int): Unit}
```

For example the following assignment would not compile

```
val r: { val callsign: String; def fly(height: Int): Unit } = Bird("pigeon")
```

because `Bird("pigeon")` is missing `callsign`.

Note the warning from the [docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#structural-types)

> Structural types are implemented with reflection at runtime, and are
>   inherently less performant than nominal types.